# how to get the value of a hidden field from a gridview using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

This is the gridview :

```
<ItemTemplate>                               
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtAction" Text='<%# Bind("ch_flcode") %>'  runat="server"
           Width="60%" Columns="50" OnChange="javascript:HandlerCodeTextChange1(this);" AutoPostBack="true"> </asp:TextBox>
           <asp:HiddenField ID="hidempCode1" runat="server" />
           <asp:HiddenField ID="hidempName1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
```

I want to use hiddenfields value in javascript

Javascript Code:

```
function HandlerCodeTextChange1(txtBox1) {
            var gv = document.getElementById("<%=gridSIupdate.ClientID%>");
           //var Rows = gv.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            if (txtBox1.value.indexOf(':') == "-1") {
                txtBox1.value = "";
                txtBox1.focus();

                gv.getElementById('<%=hidempCode1.ClientID%>').value = "";
                gv.getElementById('<%=hidempName1.ClientID%>').value = "";
            }
            else {
                var code = txtBox1.value.split(':');
                gv.getElementById('<%=hidempCode1.ClientID%>').value = code[0];
                gv.getElementById('<%=hidempName1.ClientID%>').value = code[1];
            }
        }
```

How to get hiddenfields value using javascript?

Comment: Show us the **generated** markup. What matters to JavaScript is what the browser sees, not what the server sees.

Comment: @rohit, it is better to use jquery .data() to store corresponding data in the DOM rather than rely on picking up data out of the gridview. You can render out the relevant jquery at the same time you bind your gridivew... just spit it out into a literal.

Comment: i am using ajax auto extender list in the gridview item template, these hidden fields saves the empcode and empname respectively in javascript code but i don't know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery?

```
jQuery('[id$=hidempCode1]').val();
jQuery('[id$=hidempName1]').val();
```

This selects elements that have ids ending with `hidempCode1` & `hidempName1`.

Comment: The OP is going about it the wrong way, he clearly wants to grab the ID of a specific row.

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:HiddenField>` renders as :

```
<input type="hidden">
```

Plus they have an id so you can use this to select it:

```
field = document.getElementById("hidempCode1");
```

Comment: It's not that simple in a gridview. You can't use clientidmode="Static". Without that, the id renders out as jibberish

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= hidempName1.ClientID %>
```